# JavaScript: cssText property, how can I get the absolute path of styles which use external resources in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

For a given element or selector, I can get the css rule(s) that apply to it by traversing `document.styleSheets`.
A difference between Chrome and FF that I have noticed is that for styles which use `url()`, like `url(/path/to/resource.ext)`, if there is a relative url, chrome is nice enough to output the 
absolute path, but not ff. here is an example:

**CSS:**

```
#logo{
    width:32px;
    height:23px;
    background-image:url('/img/logo.png');
    background-color:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**JS:**

```
   var selector='#logo';
   var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules)
        {
            if (rules[r].selectorText==='#logo')
            {
            console.log(rules[r].cssText);
            }
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='logo'></div>
```

In FF, the output is (relative path!)

```
console.log(rules[r].cssText);
//#logo { width: 32px; height: 23px; 
//        background-image: url("/img/logo.png"); 
//        border: 1px solid black; }
```

In Chrome, I get (absolute path!)

```
console.log(rules[r].cssText);
//#logo { width: 32px; height: 23px; border: 1px solid black; 
//        background-image: url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png); }
```

You can see the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kd7hrueu/2/

**Is there anyway to get the absolute path in FF?**

Comment: No, there isn't a way. This is browser-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. But you're going to work a little bit about it.

Every relative path inside a CSS is relative to the *stylesheet*'s location (if you don't take into account legacy Internet Explorer's "behaviors", whose paths are relative to the *document*'s location).

You can find the stylesheet's location in its `href` property, and that should alwyas be an absolute path. When you have a rule that uses `url(...)`, you should resolve the path.

```
var urlRE = /\burl\s*\(\s*([^\)]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']')\s*\)/g,
    schemaRE = /^(https?|file|data):/,
    css = rules[r].cssText, match, url;

while (match = urlRE.exec(css)) {
    url = match[1];

    // Strips the quotes if present
    if (url[0] === '"' || url[0] === "'")
        url = url.slice(1, -1);

    url = resolvePath(sheets[i].href, url);
    // do other stuff...
}

function resolvePath(base, url) {
    // The path is either absolute or a data URI
    if (schemaRE.test(url)) return url;

    // The path refers to another domain with the same schema
    if (url.substring(0, 2) === "//")
        return location.protocol + url;

    // The path is relative to the host's root
    if (url[0] === "/")
        return location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + url;

    // Gets the stylesheet's dirname
    var i = base.lastIndexOf("/");
    base = base.substring(0, i + 1);

    return base + url;
}
```

There, it's done. Well, almost. Paths can crawl up directories with `..`, but for the sake of simplicity I avoided to write a full fledged path parser.

One trick in these cases is to take advantage of anchor elements:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = url;         // e.g. http://host.com/test/../css/foo.css
console.log(a.href);  // => http://host.com/css/foo.css
```